# There is a triangle, sides = a,b,c and its angle = $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

$b=2\sqrt3$

$\sin(\alpha + \beta) + \cos(2\alpha-\beta) = 2$

Find a

I tried
$\frac{\sin\alpha}{a}=\frac{\sin\beta}{2\sqrt3}$

Or, 
Using identities 
$\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin\alpha\cdot\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\cdot\sin\beta$

But i can't solve it.
What formula should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

For $x,\sin x,\cos x\le1$

$\implies\sin(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(2\alpha-\beta)\le2$

So, we need $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=1=\cos(2\alpha-\beta)$

Also, $0<\alpha,\beta<\pi$

$\implies0<\alpha+\beta<\pi$

$0-\pi<2\alpha-\beta<2\pi-0\implies2\alpha-\beta$ has to be $0$

Comment: $0-\pi<2\alpha-\beta<2\pi-0\implies2\alpha-\beta$ how to get this sir?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter, Check the range of $2\alpha,\beta$

Comment: I dont get it sir